# How can i synchronize the getters without having an incoherent state?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I tried to synchronize the getters with adding `synchronized` to the  methods but i have always `John Odd` and `Jane Doe`. Any suggestion how can i synchronize the two Strings in that case ?

this is my code :

```
public class HonorBoard {
    private volatile String firstName;
    private volatile String lastName;


    public void set(String firstName, String lastName) {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }

    private synchronized String getFirstName() {
        return firstName ;
    }

    private synchronized String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized String toString() {
        return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HonorBoard board = new HonorBoard();
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (;;) {
                board.set("John", "Doe");
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (;;) {
                board.set("Jane", "Odd");
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (;;) {
                System.out.println(board.getFirstName() + ' ' + board.getLastName());
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is in your printing thread:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    for (;;) {
        System.out.println(board.getFirstName() + ' ' + board.getLastName());
    }
}).start();
```

There is a chance that the internal state of `board` has changed
just in between `board.getFirstName()` and `board.getLastName()`.

You could fix this issue in 2 ways.

- Either by putting a `synchronized(board) { ... }` around it

  ```
  new Thread(() -> {
      for (;;) {
          synchronized (board) {
              System.out.println(board.getFirstName() + ' ' + board.getLastName());
          }
      }
  }).start();
  ```
- or by using `board.toString()` instead, which you did already synchronize properly.

  ```
  new Thread(() -> {
      for (;;) {
          System.out.println(board.toString());
      }
  }).start();
  ```

Comment: thank you very much, your first suggestion is right, and that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

i don‘t think its possible with two getter methods. i would replace getFirstname and getLastname with getName and return either a two element string array or a java bean that holds both the first and lastname together. inside that getter method you would use a synchronized block, just like in your setter, inside that block you construct the array or the bean. i think that should work.

Comment: yes I thought to do as you said, but I want to know if there is another  solution. thank you very match